# CDK create new managed policy only if doesn't exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm setting up infrastructure using AWS CDK. Is there any way I can check if a Managed Policy already exists?

Comment: What do you mean by already exists? what kind of managed policy are you willing to check? and what for?

Comment: Did you find the solution by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the npm package [cdk-constants](https://github.com/kevinslin/cdk-constants). It "aims to be an up to date constants library for all things AWS".

While you can't use cdk-constants to programmatically check if a Managed Policy exists, you can inspect the library to see what Managed Policies are available.